# Logout in SAPUI5 application

Tags: sapui5

I want to redirect a user to Logout page after he clicks on logout. I have got it till here and redirect works. On this log out page, I want to show a link that will take the user back to login page.

Cannot hard code the link, as the code will be moved through different environments like QA, Prod etc, link will be application link will be different.

Note: I did read few blogs and saw one particular answer using ajax where we have to call some `/sap/public/bc/icf/logoff` but it throws error to me.

Reference : [Logoff/Logout function for a UI5 Apllication](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/04/20/logofflogout-function-for-a-ui5-apllication/)

***Controller.js***

```
onLogout: function(oEvent) {
        sap.m.URLHelper.redirect("logout.html", false);
    }
```

***Logout.html***

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
         <h2><span>You have been logged off.</span></h2>
    //Here want to say "Click here to login again" (Making here as a href...)
    </html>
```

Comment: Is your app inside Fiori Launchpad?

Comment: @fabiopagoti no its not inside Fiori launchpad. I developed in web IDE and its deployed in SCP as a standalone application

Comment: The api you posted is for on premise gateway. You're looking for the SCP version. This might help: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3720449

Comment: Thank you Jorg for the link. I liked the idea. But one doubt - I have to redirect to logout.html page which I have created- so I wrote the following code, but it does not show that page, rather it shows error - "Error 503: No application available to handle request". I am running from sap web ide. Any thoughts?
 onLogout: function(oEvent) {
   $.ajax({
    "url": "/services/userapi/logout",
    "success": function() {
     sap.m.URLHelper.redirect("logout.html", false);
    }
   });